# Azure Dev-Ops: "Hide the field" action missing from available actions list when configuring a process rule

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

When attempting to configure a process rule in Azure DevOps, the action "Hide the field" is not available in the drop down list for actions. I am a member of Project Collection Administrators and find it curious just those actions are missing. Has anyone experienced this? Thanks,.

Comment: Did you select a condition already?  Is that condition either "Current user is a member of a group.." or "Current user is not a member of a group.."?

Comment: Hi friend, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please check document [Hide or restrict modification of a field based on a user or group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops#hide-or-restrict-modification-of-a-field-based-on-a-user-or-group):

The `Hide Field` action is **only valid** for `Current user is a member of group...` or `Current user is not a member of group...` condition. Just as **Matt** commented, you should firstly make sure you have at least one of the above two conditions configured so that you can see `Hide Field` action.

[image]